# Can I replace my 15.6 LED laptop monitor with a generic model

Tags: laptop, display

I want to know if the monitor screens found in laptops are standardized in such a way that I don't need to track down the original monitor.

Will any 15.6 LED smooth in nicely with my laptop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

3 years of IT experience tell me that laptop screens are not standardized.  Due to the compact nature of laptops a lot of customization occurs.  Sometimes you can use a screen from a difference model from the same company, but it's more difficult to find a match from a different laptop manufacture's model.

Now, laptop OEM companies don't always make the screens themselves, but order them from another company.  If you're able to take apart your laptop, you could look for a model number on the screen and try to look it up on the internet.  I wouldn't advise this though.

The best way to find an alternative replacement is to look on ebay.  Search using your laptop model number and "replace screen".

Comment: Exactly! eBay the model, and likely you will find the right screen from the company in China that actually made the OEM version.

Answer (score -2):

Most normal 15.6 led screen can compatible with 15.6 inch laptop.

if your laptop screen is Thick,1366*768,40pin connector.

Most of 15,6 screens is compatible.

Comment: Your answer contains very little detail and completely contradicts the accepted answer. Do you have a reputable source for your claim that most screens of the same size will be compatible?

Comment: This might be true if 15.6 was an odd size and only one screen manufacturer made it.  In most cases, though, screens from different manufacturers aren't plug-and-play interchangeable.